# Good theoretical physics introduction for 6 year old very advanced in math?

Tags: education, mathematics, resource-recommendations

I think now is a good time to introduce my son to theoretical physics.  He asks so many questions about the universe, black holes, gravity, atoms, molecules, light, etc.  He's borderline obsessed with the idea of more than 3 space dimensions.  And he tries to apply math to everything.  So I'd love to find a great introductory book, lecture, online class or something of that nature to feed his curiosity.

The issue is he's only 6 years old (his birthday was only a few months ago).  So his life experience is obviously very limited.  His vocabulary and general knowledge is probably not a whole lot more than the average 1st grader.  However, his math skills are extraordinary.  He's working on calculus now, having mastered algebra and everything that's come before.

Is there any introductory physics material that is heavy on the math and light on the vocabulary and assumed general knowledge?  This would also be beneficial to non-native English speakers.

Comment: This is trolling if I've ever seen it.

Comment: Book recommendation questions are pretty tightly restricted around here; in particular, we don't allow ones that duplicate existing topics. Take a look at the answers to the linked duplicate question and see if they would be appropriate. However, if you can elaborate on the reasons why the standard intro materials would not be appropriate for your son, then perhaps this can stand on its own and in that case I'd be willing to reopen it.

Comment: I think the books recommended in the linked question are for a very different question.  I'm looking for any introductory material for a young kid.  Typical physics books are too difficult for him to read.  The math is easy, but the vocabulary and word density is hard.  It would him too long to get through and he doesn't have that focus and discipline.

Comment: Hm, similar to Chris Gerig, I`m not sure what to think about this... If it is serious Your son could probably watch some of Lenny Susskind`s very accessible courses about different topics in theoretical physics (they are correct and introduce the necessary maths in a simplified manner) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Susskind or start to read Demystified Books about what piques him, they contain easy to follow step by step calculations, for example about QM http://www.amazon.de/Quantum-Mechanics-Demystified-David-McMahon/dp/0071455469

Comment: As You can see looking at the last picture of this review, little children seem to like this: http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2012/02/gambini-and-pullin-first-course-in-loop.html?showComment=1330425180939 ... (Sorry that I could not hold myself back linking to this funny picture of the little girl with this book :-P)

Comment: @Dilaton - your recommendations are exactly what I was looking for.  I'm watching Lenny Susskind's fall 2011 classical mechanics lecture on YouTube right now and I love his style.  I think my son might really enjoy these.  The Demystified book series looks ideal.  However, I read through some pages of those books.. they're heavy on math, which is perfect.  But they all also assume quite a bit of knowledge in physics and other areas and are clearly meant to be read by an adult.  They would be very hard for my son to read through.

What made you think I wasn't serious about my question?

Comment: Oh, just throwing some ideas out there: it would be good if you explained tge basics of classical physics yourself:like acceleration, gravity, etc. Teaching him a bit of electromagnetism won't hurt, though he'll need a more solid foundation on forces. Some other stuff: A Brief History Of Time, Stephen Hawking. The Elegant Universe, Brian Greene. There are NOVA videos free on their site of the PBS NOVA show with the same name.

Comment: @at.: Yeah, I just love Lenny Susskind for giving these nice lectures; the funny comments he throws in sometimes make me LOL a lot. Sorry that I first was suspicious seeing Your question; there are just too many evil people popping up at physics sites these days who just make fun of and pick at theoretical physics and physicists :-( ... It sometimes happens here at physics SE too. So I apologize and congratulate You on having such a bright little physicist son, he is an amazing little boy :-) Cheers

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Can this be reopened such that I can put my first comment which was useful to the asker as an answer such that it does not get lost? It is clear that the question is meant serious now ...

Comment: @Dilaton If the question is edited to make it clear why the answers to existing book recommendation questions are not suitable, and if it is of sufficiently general interest, then yes, it can be reopened. Regarding the "general interest" criterion, one might consider rephrasing the question such that it would also be useful to non-native English speakers, for example.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I agree with Dilaton that it should be opened. ( there is no link to a duplicate question at present. I do not know if it has been edited out). If Mozart could play the piano at three I do not see why a six year old might not master the maths. There could be more of these wonder kids out there that the internet age could help.

Comment: Parents are easily duped by children into thinking they know more than they actually do. I remember, I was a child once. Parents hardly know how to identify fakery, so that if you learn the noun/verb/adjective status of "quark", "confined", "black hole" and "radiate" you can make lots of impressive sentences. In order to have understanding, you must solve a few problems, and this takes effort, and children are lazy. On the other hand, I do think that a 6 year old can _actually_ understand this stuff, because there isn't much to it. But have the 6 year old ask for himself here.